# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: list object has no element Undefined

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I'm not good in javascript. I have google charts with data. And I need to add data to charts via loop in javascript:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    data.addRow(
        ['{{list[i][0]}}',
        { v: {{list[i][1][0]}}, f: '{{list[i][1][1]}}' }]
        );
}
```

What did contain a list:

```
list = ['Car', [2:30, '2:30'], '1:00']
```

But it wrote me an error:

```
UndefinedError
```

jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: list object has no element Undefined

Can you advice me please, what I can do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the Google Charts API, but from the looks of it, you have a syntax error since you're literally passing the string `'{{list[i][0]}}'` to the `data.addrow()` method.

Try this instead and let me know if it works:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  data.addRow([
    list[i][0],
    {
      v: list[i][1][0],
      f: list[i][1][1]
    }
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, timpa, thank you for your answering. It's now worked for me, cause my var list is rendered from flask-app into html, so it couldn't define list. But I found the answer, I will write it below.

Answer (score 1):

I think this error because you try access index of Undefined class, for example if `list[i]` is empty so list[0] will be Undefined in this case no jinja errors, but if you try access the first index of `list[i]` like this `list[i][0]` this time jinja will raise exception,

> object has no element 0
> that's because `list[i]` is Undefined

to avoid this error use if statement to check the length of list **using the length filter** and make sure it bigger than the fixed index you are using for example

`{% if list[i]|length > 0 %}{{list[i][0]}}{% endif %}` and so on,

also you can pass type function to the template in render template and check type of variable for better understand eg

```
render_template("index.html", type=type)
```

in index.html

```
{{type(list[i])}}
{{type(list[i][1])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Try like this:

```
{% for i in range(list|length) %}
    data.addRow(
        ['{{list[i][0]}}',
        { v: {{list[i][1][0]}}, f: '{{list[i][1][1]}}' }]
        );
{% endfor %}
```

It's no javascript, I know. But helped me to solve the problem.